# Messaging.SingleEmailMessaging Sends duplicate emails to recipient

Tags: singleemailmessage

I am trying to send Krow expense list files to an email address. I have that functionality working, however it does send duplicate emails. I have added a debug message just before the sendEmail method is called, which prints out the email list size.

This message prints out the correct size for the number of emails I am expecting to send. For example if there is one expense line, one email is created and the size is 1.

This occurs in both sandbox and production.

Here is the Apex code:

```
public class ExpenseToXeroEmail {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendExpenseEmail(List<Id> expenseIdList) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        String[] emailAddrs = new String[]{'test@email.com'};
        for (Id expenseId : expenseIdList) {
            List<Krow__Expense_Line__c> expenseLines = [SELECT Name FROM Krow__Expense_Line__c WHERE Krow__Expense__c = :expenseId];

            for (Krow__Expense_Line__c line : expenseLines) {
                String name = '%' + line.Name + '%';
                // Getting files: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205970/how-to-find-a-user-uploaded-txt-file-by-name-and-get-the-text-in-my-apex-class
                List<ContentVersion> files = [SELECT Id, Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title LIKE :name AND IsLatest = True];

                if (files.size() > 0) {                 
                    // Email file: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-email-attachment-using-process-builder-shweta-soparkar-/
                    Blob data = files[0].VersionData;

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                    attach.setBody(data);
                    attach.setFileName(files[0].Title);

                    email.setToAddresses(emailAddrs);
                    email.setSubject('Attachment for ' + files[0].Title);
                    email.setPlainTextBody('Please find attached expense reciept');
                    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});

                    System.Debug(email);

                    if (!emails.contains(email)) {
                        emails.add(email);
                    }

                }
            }            
        }
        System.debug('Number of emails to send' + emails.size());
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas, or if you need any more information.

Comment: Your code is written in such a way that it will send maximum `expenseIdList.size() * expenseIdList.size()` emails to same addresses. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is not what I wanted. It should send a maximum of `expensIdList.size() * expenseLines.size()` emails to the same address. 

Can you please let me know where you are getting `expenseIdList.size() * expenseIdList.size()`? So I can see if I can fix it?

Comment: Apologies, your code is doing exactly that, ending `expensIdList.size() * expenseLines.size()` emails to same address. What is the issue you are having? And can you explain what do you mean by duplicate emails? Sending same content?

Comment: It is sending exactly the same email twice. Though the list of emails only contains one email at the `System.Debug('Number of emails to send' + emails.size());`.

I can see if I can clean up my logs of company data, and add them to my post if you think it will help?